# Lots of conflicts in Pods project after using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

I am just starting using CocoaPods to integrate some libraries to my project.
When I and my teammates both run pod install to install the new library everything seems fine. However, when I am pulling her code from our repository I got a huge amount of conflicts in Pods project. 535 to be exact.

[image]

[image]

I do not think this is normal and I think it's kinda crazy to choose mine or her manually. In fact I do not really know whose code I should keep.

Any ideas on what to do with this? Any ideas on how to avoid this in the future?

Comment: The easy way out here is to remove this project and re-run `pod install`

Comment: @KeithSmiley Are you saying to delete the workspace and podfile, and just redo "pod install"?

Comment: Yes if you do that it should fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be overly concerned about conflicts in your Pods project. The best you can do is to ensure that you are both using the same version of cocoapods as there is a world of difference between minor version. Once you have confirmed this, you can safely take her code and you should not have any further conflicts.

The workspace, Pods directory and contents and also the Pods project file are all dynamically generated by cocoapods.

It is routinely safe to remove your workspace file, pods project file and entire pods directory when you have pod issues. It is up to you whether you what to check them into your source control or not. in Particular the Pods directory. There are pros and cons of doing this. By checking everything, your app will build instantly from a pure checkout but as you are currently experiencing, but you cannot guarantee that a pod install with run successfully (if a reference pod becomes unavailable).

I prefer to at least at /Pods to .gitignore as pod install should run from a CI server without fail.

Use something like this [template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore) is always a good start.